one bug from kfac_jax
I am coding one neural network Quantum Monte Carlo software. I already finished all modules. However, when I try to use kfac_jax to optimize the parameters, I meet one bug,
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Attempt to donate the same buffer twice in Execute() (second use: flattened argument 1, replica 0). Toy example for this bug: f(donate(a), donate(a)).
I can run optimizer.init successfully.
anyone has ideas about this?
I dont konw how to find the sources of this bug.

Please edit your question to add a minimal reproducible example demonstrating your issue. Without this, it's unlikely that anybody will be able to answer your question.
